# How to change images with just one button with jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am newbie to programming, but still learning...

**My problem is:** I want to change images, three of them, with one button and with some `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animation. So, first all of them (images) are hidden,then with a single click first picture appear with fadeIn effect, then with next single click first picture disappear and second picture appear and so on...

This is my html..

```
<button id="animeButton">Animate</button> <br>
<img id="firstPic" class="images" src="http://paladone.com/ 
image/cache/data/Pacman/PP2723PM_pac_man_ghost_pixel_bricks-800x800.jpg">
<img id="secondPic" class="images" src="http://i2.wp.com/loyalkng.com/wp-      
content/uploads/2009/05/furious-george.jpg?w=557">
<img id="thirdPic" class="images" src="http://www.wallpaperist.com/ 
wallpapers/Cartoons/Donald-duck-furious-800-600.jpg">
```

This is my jq...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".images").hide();    
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#animeButton").click(function(){
$("#firstPic").fadeIn(2000);
//dunno what to write next....
});
});
```

Comment: Add your html and jquery as text to your post

Comment: Ok, i just added the code block. Thanks for useful comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, check it out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.images').hide();

  var counter = 0;
  var picArray = [];

  $("div").find("img").each(function(index, value) {
    picArray[index] = $(this);
  })

  $('#animeButton').click(function() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      picArray[picArray.length - 1].fadeOut(2000, function() {
        picArray[counter].fadeIn(2000);
        counter++;
      })

    } else {
      picArray[counter - 1].fadeOut(2000, function() {
        picArray[counter].fadeIn(2000);
        counter++;
        if (counter > picArray.length - 1) {
          counter = 0;
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="animeButton">
  Animate
</button>
<br/>

<div>
  <img id="firstPic" class="images" src="http://paladone.com/image/cache/data/Pacman/PP2723PM_pac_man_ghost_pixel_bricks-800x800.jpg">

  <img id="secondPic" class="images" src="http://i2.wp.com/loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/furious-george.jpg?w=557">

  <img id="thirdPic" class="images" src="http://www.wallpaperist.com/ 
wallpapers/Cartoons/Donald-duck-furious-800-600.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zorken17. Works like a clock

Comment: You are welcome! And it is a dynamic code so you can add how many images as you like

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to add a data attribute, something like

```
<img id="firstPic" data-id="1" class="images" src="http://paladone.com/ 
    image/cache/data/Pacman/PP2723PM_pac_man_ghost_pixel_bricks-800x800.jpg">
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    imgID = 1;
    $("#animeButton").click(function(){
        if (imgID>3) {
           imgID = 1
        }
        $($('[data-id="'+imgID+'"]')).fadeIn(2000);
        imgID = imgID+1
    });
});
```

It's not tested yet, but it should work.

Comment: please tell us if it worked just to be sure this was what you expected

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer. Yep, but i need to make first picture disappear when second on emerge and second one to disappear when third one emerge. Also i want to make them with some animate effect...

Comment: you can place a container div, and then add the image inside that container

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".images").hide();

  var picArr = ["firstPic","secondPic","thirdPic"];
  // set attr to button to store next pic
  $("#animeButton").attr("nextPic", picArr[0]);
  var c = 0;

  $("#animeButton").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this).attr("nextPic");
    var currVisible = $(".images:visible").attr("id");
    $("#" + btn).fadeIn(2000, function() {
      c += 1;
      if (c >= picArr.length) c = 0;
      $("#animeButton").attr("nextPic", picArr[c]);
    });
    $("#" + currVisible).fadeOut(2000);
  });
});
```